# Weblogic deployment state installed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I created a rest web application using below Technologies.

**Back end**
 - java 8 , Spring (4.1.4) and JdbcTemplat

**Front end**
 - java 8 , Spring (4.1.4) and jsf (2.1)

I deployed my war files (back end and front end) on my local Weblogic server (12.1.3.0.0) successfully.

But, when the same war files are deployed in our test weblogic server, the below states are returned (I changed required log paths and back end base url on front end ,according to the test server).

**Test Weblogic Server(12.2.1.3.0)**

1. Back end state  - **Installed**
2. Front end state - **Installed**

Please anyone help me understand this problem.?

Comment: How did you deploy your application, with a wlst script or with the admin console ? You have to "start" your application once it is installed.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin . I used admin console and after the deployment , I used "Change Center" tab to activate changes (Using Activate Changes button)
Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Once you have activated your changes the application is installed. You have to start it now with the console.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I'll try and let you know if there is any issue.
Also, Could you please tell me the meaning of the state "Installed" and " Prepared" of weblogic server deployment admin console.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Installed : Application is added to the domain's configuration but changes are not yet active
Prepared : Changes have be activated. The configuration update is commited. All servers know this new application but cannot serve it
Active : Application is ready to serve requests.